# ¿Cómo manipular foto?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Tengo un pequeño problema, toda la funcion listada a continuación es usada para poder tomar una foto desde una web, pero resulta que la foto que tomé necesito subirla al servidor guardando la dirección de destino en la BD.

Pero lo que no se es cómo puedo o podría manipular dicho resultado.

```
$scope.iniciarCamara = function()
  {
    $scope.camaraWeb  = true;
    $scope.clickFotoPausar = function()
    {
      video.pause();
    }

    $scope.clickFotoOcultar = function()
    {
      $scope.camaraWeb  = false;
    }

    $scope.clickFotoApagar = function()
    {
      document.location.reload();
    }

    // Obtenemos todos los elementos que necesitaremos
    var video              = document.querySelector('#camera-stream'),
        image              = document.querySelector('#snap'),
        start_camera       = document.querySelector('#start-camera'),
        controls           = document.querySelector('.controls'),
        take_photo_btn     = document.querySelector('#take-photo'),
        delete_photo_btn   = document.querySelector('#delete-photo'),
        download_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#download-photo'),
        error_message      = document.querySelector('#error-message');


    // Utilizamos la funcion getUserMedia para obtener la salida de la webcam
    navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                          navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                          navigator.msGetUserMedia);


    if(!navigator.getMedia){
      displayErrorMessage("Tu navegador no soporta la funcion getMedia.");
    }
    else{

      // Solicitamos la camara
      navigator.getMedia(
        {
          video: true
        },
        function(stream){

          // A nuestro componente video le establecemos el src al stream de la webcam
          video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

          // Reproducimos
          video.play();
          video.onplay = function() {
            showVideo();
          };

        },
        function(err){
          displayErrorMessage("Ocurrio un error al obtener el stream de la webcam, carga la página de nuevo ó vuelve a intentarlo mas tarde: " + err.name, err);
        }
      );

    }



    // En los moviles no se puede reproducir el video automaticamente, programamos funcionamiento del boton inicar camara
    start_camera.addEventListener("click", function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      // Reproducimos manualmente
      video.play();
      showVideo();

    });


    take_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      var snap = takeSnapshot();

      // Mostramos la imagen
      image.setAttribute('src', snap);
      image.classList.add("visible");

      // Activamos los botones de eliminar foto y descargar foto
      delete_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");
      download_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");

      // Establecemos el atributo href para el boton de descargar imagen
      download_photo_btn.href = snap;

      // Pausamos el stream de video de la webcam
      //video.pause();

    });


    delete_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      // Ocultamos la imagen
      image.setAttribute('src', "");
      image.classList.remove("visible");

      // Deshabilitamos botones de descargar y eliminar foto
      delete_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");
      download_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");

      // Reanudamos la reproduccion de la webcam
      video.play();

    });



    function showVideo(){
      // Mostramos el stream de la webcam y los controles

      hideUI();
      video.classList.add("visible");
      controls.classList.add("visible");
    }


    function takeSnapshot(){

      var hidden_canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
          context = hidden_canvas.getContext('2d');

      var width = video.videoWidth,
          height = video.videoHeight;

      if (width && height) {

        // Configuramos el canvas con las mismas dimensiones que el video
        hidden_canvas.width = width;
        hidden_canvas.height = height;

        // Hacemos una copia
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

        // Convertimos la imagen del canvas en datarurl
        return hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      }
    }


    function displayErrorMessage(error_msg, error){
      error = error || "";
      if(error)
      {
        console.log(error);
      }
      error_message.innerText = error_msg;

      hideUI();
      error_message.classList.add("visible");

    }


    function hideUI(){
      // Limpiamos

      controls.classList.remove("visible");
      start_camera.classList.remove("visible");
      video.classList.remove("visible");
      snap.classList.remove("visible");
      error_message.classList.remove("visible");
    }

  };
```

Comment: create un form que se envie desde tu js con ajax o submit como quieras y que tenga un campo de tipo file y asi le puedes enviar al servidor y allí ya hacer con ella lo que quieras, renombrarla guardarla en la bd etc

Comment: Es que la cuestion surge ahi, como puedo hacer que al momento de tomar la foto y que el usuario quiera subir esa foto por medio de otra funcion. Esto me esta dando dolores de cabeza.